# python multiporcessing not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing in python 2.7.7. I tried to implement this example:

```
import multiprocessing

def worker():
    """worker function"""
    print 'Worker'
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

This code is from https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html.

My problem is, that I can't see any output of the worker process.
What is the problem here?

**EDIT:** My operating system is Windows 7 64bit.

**EDIT:** It is working, if I call the python-script from the windows command line (with `python script.py`). Previous I started the script from IDLE (`Run Module (F5)`) and this was not working.

Comment: can you put debug point inside worker() check if its reaching

Comment: @virendrao I don't think so - python 2 here ;)

Comment: @wewa there is no problem with your code, kindly check if your are facing any OS/Configuration related issues.

Comment: Checked your code...runs fine with me...

Comment: @IronFist which OS and python version are you using?

Comment: Check in Windows7...will check it in Linux Ubuntu as well...

Comment: Works fine in Ubuntu..

Comment: @anand how should I check for those OS/Configuration related issues?

Comment: @wewa Its a painful thing to do, but here are the steps;  Open up your python command line interpreter. > Import you module > Check if it represents the same as intended or it is something else > Check you simple function call back with no multiprocess > then add code step by step while testing.

Comment: @IronFist when you check in Windows7, did you call your script from the windows command line or did you run it out from IDLE?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `p.join()` on those processes as per the examples in the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Depending on your OS and python implementation it may be because job control kills your sub-processes when the main process exits (I did not try).

Comment: I tried `p.join()` but I doesn't change anything. But this is no way for me, because `p.join()` would block the calling/main-thread.

Comment: I don't think that sub-processes are killed because the main process exits. I tried to hold the main process open with a `while(1):` but this didn't change anything.

Comment: No problem. I was guessing. And with your edit (OS=Windows) the argument is moot anyway.